# How to unchek a checkbox using jquery when check the other one in a array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi guys I have a "datatable" with the following checkboxes on it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="total_balance[]"  id="total_balance" class="total_balance" value="<?= $balance['supplierID'] ?>" />

<input type="checkbox" name="no_payment[]"  id="no_payment" class="no_payment" value="<?= $balance['supplierID'] ?>" />
```

That is a loop, so I've hundred of the same names but with different values by row.
So what I want is when I check the total_balance[] that has the value=1, for example, it's uncheck, if is checked, the no_payment[] with value=1, and so on.. like if I click the total_balance[] with value=32, uncheck the no_payment with value=32...

How to I do that in jquery??

I've tried like that:

```
$('input[name="total_balance"]').change(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
        var val = this.value;
        $('input:no_payment[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', false);
     });


      $('input[name="no_payment"]').change(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
        var val = this.value;
        $('input:total_balance[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', false);
     });
```

but doesn't work

tks!

Comment: Are the checkboxes always side by side?  You can access the next or previous element with $(this).prev() and $(this).next()

Comment: Something with `index()` and `eq()` comes to mind. If you have many chackboxes, use a "class" and not an "id". An "id" should be unique within a page. ...  [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it:

```
$('.total_balance').click(function() {
        var val = this.value;
        $('.no_payment[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', false);
     });


      $('.no_payment').click(function() {
        var val = this.value;
        $('.total_balance[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', false);
     })
```